# Excessive spaces in ListView.separated

Tags: flutter, dart

When I look for the pressure I need, for some reason it is not created at the beginning, but with some gaps, how do I fix this?

[image]

Here's the code:

```
 Widget pressureItem(int index) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
    child: Material(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 28, 28, 31),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    pressures[index].pressure,
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      fontSize: 23,
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 15.0,
                    height: 15.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: getPressureColor(
                                  double.parse(pressures[index]
                                      .pressure
                                      .toString()
                                      .split('/')[0]),
                                  double.parse(pressures[index]
                                      .pressure
                                      .toString()
                                      .split('/')[1]
                                      .split('-')[0])),
                              blurRadius: 5.0)
                        ],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                        color: getPressureColor(
                            double.parse(pressures[index]
                                .pressure
                                .toString()
                                .split('/')[0]),
                            double.parse(pressures[index]
                                .pressure
                                .toString()
                                .split('/')[1]
                                .split('-')[0]))),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  pressures[index].action.isEmpty
                      ? Container()
                      : Text(
                          pressures[index].action,
                          style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          ),
                        ),
                  Text(
                    '${DateFormat.MMMd('en_US').format(pressures[index].date)} в ${DateFormat.jm('en_US').format(pressures[index].date)}',
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 15, 15),
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        toolbarHeight: 90,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: customTextField(
            hintText: 'Search pressure...',
            controller: findPressureController),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: pressures.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Obx(
              () => textInput.value.isNotEmpty
                  ? pressures[index].pressure.contains(textInput.value) ||
                          pressures[index]
                              .date
                              .toString()
                              .contains(textInput.value)
                      ? pressureItem(index)
                      : Container()
                  : pressureItem(index),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
              const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
List pressures = [
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '111/81-55',
      action: 'Wake up',
      date: DateTime(2022, 12, 12, 12, 18)),
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '125/63-48',
      action: 'After a two-hour walk.',
      date: DateTime(2022, 12, 30, 15, 08)),
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '150/117-81', date: DateTime(2022, 12, 10, 21, 30)),
  PressureModel(
      pressure: '170/101-92',
      action: 'Doing push-ups',
      date: DateTime(2022, 12, 11, 08, 25)),
];
```

Ignore this text, it's for StackOverflow, it tells me that my text consists mostly of code
Ignore this text, it's for StackOverflow, it tells me that my text consists mostly of code
Ignore this text, it's for StackOverflow, it tells me that my text consists mostly of code
Ignore this text, it's for StackOverflow, it tells me that my text consists mostly of code

Comment: could you include your listview too?

Comment: The way you structed it you can potentially return an empty `Container` for a given index. Most likely you have something like `pressureItem` -> separator -> empty container -> another separator -> another empty container -> another separator -> `pressureItem`, etc. The separators add up and create extra space between the `pressureItem`s.

Comment: @eamirho3ein, yes, just a second.

Comment: @Alexandr I mean your list view that you use pressureItem inside it, not you list data.

Comment: @eamirho3ein, sorry, I don't understand what you want, all the code I have is in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter your `pressures`, because when you try to return empty `container` in your listview's builder, it builds a `separator` for it and that cause your issue, so change it to this:

```
{
 ....
    
    List newList;
    Obx(
      () => newList = textInput.value.isNotEmpty
          ? pressures.where((element) =>
              element.pressure.contains(textInput.value) ||
              element.date.toString().contains(textInput.value))
          : pressures,
    );
    
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 15, 15),
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            toolbarHeight: 90,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            title: customTextField(
                hintText: 'Search pressure...',
                controller: findPressureController),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemCount: newList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return pressureItem(index);
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```